# ListView with images and text

Tags: android, listview

What's the way to create a listview with images on the left side and text right after it?
(Note: the images were previously downloaded from the Net)
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am troubling with listview which should contain Image(on Left side) and Text (On Right Side) but i want to do it programmatically....any help pls

Answer (score 5):

Here's a complete sample code [Lazy load of images in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/android-how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview/3068012#3068012). You can reuse it.

If you have new items in the list you just call `adapter.notifyDatasetChanged()` and `ListView` will redisplay all items including the new ones.

The `getView()` method in adapter inflates item.xml and displays real data in it. You need to start with some basic `ListView` tutorial, such as the one at [Android Series: Custom ListView items and adapters](http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/).

Comment: Ya i have already tried it...but i want to Display RSS Feed's Image and text ...is it helpful ?

Comment: Of course it is. What exactly problem do you have?

Comment: Actually i want to set Image and a text whenever i am having a new item in ListView at Run-Time (i.e. total no. of items are not fixed)

Comment: That's OK. Adapter can do it. If you have new items in the list you just call adapter.notifyDatasetChanged() and ListView will redisplay all items including the new ones.

Comment: m confused regarding listview with image and text....let me know pls..in lazyloading you have defined items.xml file which contains <imageview> and <textview> , so how you call this layout for each item in a listview ? for example, i wants to have 10 items such as Name[10], photo[10], now i want to display this data in listview...then what i have to do ?...thanx for such help

Comment: Adapter does it all. getView() method in adapter inflates item.xml and displays real data in it. You need to start with some basic ListView tutorial, this one for example http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/.

Comment: ya I came to know that we can set custom view in ListView by using getView() method...and thanx for providing an example.

Comment: @Fedor.........even this example is the easiest for the beginner: http://www.androidpeople.com/android-custom-listview-tutorial-example/

Answer (score 1):

A ListView item can have it's own custom layout.  When you create your adapter for the ListView you can pass in the layout id to the Adapter constructor.  See [SimpleAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.html) and [ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html).

=> You will have to extend an Adapter and implement **`getView()`** to property set the image+text.

Answer (score 0):

Hi this class is used to make the image to bind with list view use simple adater and use the following class

```
class MyViewBinder implements ViewBinder {
                    public boolean setViewValue(View view, Object data,String textRepresentation) {
                        if( (view instanceof ImageView) & (data instanceof Bitmap) ) {
                            ImageView iv = (ImageView) view;
                            Bitmap bm = (Bitmap) data;  
                            iv.setImageBitmap(bm);  
                            return true;
                        }


                        return false;
                    }
                  }
```